# Ajax script Does not save Email input to Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, foreach

The script below stores the users email with Product Name and ID, however the email is not being passed/stored to the Database. As it is in a loop I've made the input / modal ID's unique by adding the product ID to each instance.

The code works on individual product pages.

HTML:

```
    <?php foreach($searchresults["products"] as $product): ?>
    <?php
    $pidForSubscribe = $product['id'];
    $priceForSubscribe = $product['price'];
    ?>

    <!-- modal button -->
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-subscribe" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subscribe-<?php print $product['id'];?>">


    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="subscribe-<?php print $product['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php print $product["name"]; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body row">

      <?php require("subscribe.php") ?>

        </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Subscribe.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function subscribeEmail(pid,price)
{
    var email = document.getElementById('subemail-<?php print $product['id'];?>').value;

    if (this.email == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter email');
        return false;
    }
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      var url = "html/subscribeAjax.php?pid="+pid+"&price="+price+"&email="+email;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


</script>

<div class="row subscribe">
    <form name="form2" id="form2">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 nopadding">
            <input type="text" name="subemail" id="subemail-<?php print $product['id'];?>" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 nopadding">
            <button name="subbtn" id="subbtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="subscribeEmail(<?php echo $pidForSubscribe;?>,<?php echo $priceForSubscribe;?>)" type="button">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

subscribeAjax.php

```
<?php
require("../includes/common.php");


$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$price = $_GET['price'];

$squery = "SELECT * FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."updateprice` WHERE `product_id` =".$pid." AND `email` = '".$email."'";

$numRows = database_querySelect($squery,$rows);

if($numRows)
{
    echo "You are already subscribed!!";
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."updateprice` (`product_id`,`price`,`email`) VALUES ($pid,'$price','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
    $insertedId = mysql_insert_id();

    if($insertedId)
    {
        echo "You are successfully subscribed!!";
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."updateprice` SET `price` = '$price' WHERE `product_id` = ".$pid) or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: Did u check in Developers tool, whether EMAIL value is getting passed in ajax call

Comment: No it's not being passed in the ajax call

Comment: Try to pass Hardcore value to EMAIL instead of `document.getElementById('subemail-<?php print $product['id'];?>').value;`

Comment: `var email='YourEmail';`

Comment: Yes, this passes the email. Could it be because the form (subscribe.php) opens in a modal and the input ID is in php?

Comment: Got it working - sort of - I enter the email first time okay, then enter another email but it passes the first email again (even after refreshing the page)

Comment: Are you storing value of email in SESSION or COOKIE.

Comment: No I don't think so, How could I check that?

Comment: rslsrl@gmail.com this is my email id please send me above code there. I'll help u to provide right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ajax code like this. The `XMLHttpRequest Object` have to created outside the ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function subscribeEmail(pid,price)
{
    var email = document.getElementById('subemail-<?php print $product['id'];?>').value;

    if (this.email == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter email');
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      var url = "html/subscribeAjax.php?pid="+pid+"&price="+price+"&email="+email;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: is it only email or rest of the values too ??

Comment: did you try alerting & echoing the result you are getting from html/subscribeAjax.php